# How to make regex accept only one optional underscore?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regex that accepts alphanumeric characters and few other language characters. Now I want to allow only one optional underscore (_) anywhere in the string. Can you please help on how to achieve it?

```
const serverUserRegex = /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/ug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward way to enforce this would be to add the following negative lookahead assertion to the start of the pattern:

```regex
(?!.*_.*_)
```

This would reject any input having two (or more) underscores, which means that zero or one underscores would be acceptable.  Your updated pattern:

```js
const serverUserRegex = /^(?!.*_.*_)[_\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/ug
//                                   ^^ add underscore to your character class here
```

Comment: this is failing when I test in this website (https://regex101.com/) and my app. To test in website: ^(?!.*_.*_)[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\\u3000-\\u303f\\u3040-\\u309f\\u30a0-\\u30ff\\uff00-\\uff9f\\u4e00-\\u9faf\\u3400-\\u4dbf\\u3130-\\u318F\\uAC00-\\uD7AF]+$

Comment: `this is failing` ... _what_ exactly is failing?

Comment: I mean it is not matching for _

Comment: I get it.  I thought that your current character class would have already included underscore.  If not, then just add it.